# Could I run Visual Studio and check code into SVN, installed on Ubuntu, on the same machine?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, svn, lamp

My original question was going to be "Can a Windows process communicate with Linux running in a VM on the same machine?" but this is a little more specific.

I'm going to get a new machine soon, and was planning on Dual Booting Win7 and Ubuntu. I thought I might run Visual Studio in Windows, and have a LAMP set up in Ubuntu, on which I would host an SVN repository. However, obviously I cannot have VS and SVN running simultaneously with this set up.

This made me wonder if it would be possible to run Ubuntu in a VM, and check code into SVN from Visual Studio that way?

I'm entirely open to answers telling me this is a stupid idea, as long as you can give me a more reasonable one.

(I'm not sure if this is a really bad question or not, sorry if it's too waffly and not really asking anything specific.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your virtual machine behaves like a real computer. You have numerous options to connect your physical hardware with your virtual machine via network interfaces ([Virtual Box Manual Chapter about networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)). After configuring your virtual machines network interface, setting up LAMP/SVN should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Good to know. Is this a bit of a retarded thing to want to do though?

Comment: Well, if you backup your SVN regularly, I see no downside to your approach.